# Access AWS S3 protected Images from Flutter/Dart?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, amazon-s3, minio

I've got some image files stored in my S3 bucket.

I'd like these to display only in my flutter client but not be publicly accessible IE: In a web browser.

I'm using Flutter's Minio MinIO Dart Client SDK to upload the images to the bucket.

[https://pub.dev/packages/minio](https://MinIO%20Dart%20Client%20SDK)

The images appear in the bucket as read/write only for the object owner.

What the best way to access these images in Flutter?

I was looking into using pre-signed urls but I wonder if this will create a big lag time?

If so, I'll probably scrap the idea and just make the images publicly available to everyone because I'm using a lot of images in my app.

Comment: What did you end up going with? I'm just about to upload images to s3 with Flutter. It seems like it would be less work to have a long lived url for each image so you can store it in the database, but I haven't looked into it much.

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet, so at the moment I'm leaving them all as publicly accessible.

Comment: Hi all! Any update on this? I am trying to have s3 for media storage of my flutter/firebase app but I don't want my media to be available to everyone on the internet... However I am using Firebase Auth so I don't kn ow how to limit access of my S3 bucket to only those people who are registered on my app

Comment: Not at the moment. My project is temporarily on hold.

Answer (score 0):

You can create IAM policy on a bucket and give the users access to those buckets. [Refer](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/security/minio-identity-management/policy-based-access-control.html) . You can o with presigned urls as well but that will last for 7 days max

Comment: Any suggestions for how to implement this? How do I give users access to those buckets? Shall I put the access keys in the Minio code within the app? If so is this risky in case someone hacks the code? final minio = Minio(
    endPoint: 's3.amazonaws.com',
    accessKey: 'YOUR-ACCESSKEYID',
    secretKey: 'YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY',
  );

  final stream = await minio.getObject('BUCKET-NAME', 'OBJECT-NAME');

Answer (score 0):

The implementation logic can be found [here](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-multi-user-quickstart-guide.html) . The policy ,users and attaching th epolicy to user are done by MinIO Admin and its a one time activity.  Dont hard code access key /secret key for creating the client. You can keep those in any property file or any other location. The client can read the access/secret key and create the user. Since the user has the policy attached to it , it will work in accordance to its policy.  The MinIO team is available on their public slack channel or by email to answer questions 24/7/365.